# Building the Id of CheckBox in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a DropDownList:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)SlotList[counter], new { id = "slotDDL_" + @item.ResourceID, tid = @item.ResourceID, @class = "slotDDL_ text white" })
```

and a CheckboxFor:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelected, new { @class = "boxcheck_", id = @item.ResourceID })
```

When executing this:

```
 $('.slotDDL_').change(function () {
            var resId = $(this).attr("tid");
            IsSelected = 'boxcheck_' + resId;
            alert($('#' + resId).attr("checked"));
      });
```

I get the following :

```
alert($(this).attr("tid"))====>505
alert(IsSelected)====> boxcheck_505
alert($('#' + resId).attr("checked"))===>undefined
```

**Question:**
How can I successfully build the string of my Id ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have you checked your final HTML source? is the checkbox id 505??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelected, new { @class = "boxcheck_", id = "@item.ResourceID" })
```

You missed `"` for `id` attribute

Comment: It was more than that actually : 'id = "boxcheck_" + @item.ResourceID'. Great catch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put '#' instead of '.'

```
$('#slotDDL_')
```

Comment: @class = "slotDDL_ text white"  i need to access it by class. Again ... I can access the function. I get alerts. I have problem constructing the name of the ID .